# How do I get a sum of time estimates in Jira issue search?

Tags: jira

I have a JIRA issue filter which has a list of all my tasks for a given sprint and includes the time estimates.
I can export it to excel and then convert the seconds of my tasks to hours but it is an ugly solution.

Does anyone know of a plugin or a way to get this information from JIRA instead of using export?
[image: I would like a sum here or above the column]

Answer (score 2):

The Script Runner add-on has some experimental JQL functions that will do this: https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-AggregateExpressions

Comment: is there also a free alternative ?